# Angular ui-router 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement some multiple views as described in the [link](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views) but cannot get this working. Here is what I do

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {UIRouterModule} from 'ui-router-ng2';
import { Header } from './routes/header.component';
import { Navigation } from './routes/navigation.component';
import { Content } from './routes/content.component';

let rootState = {
  name: 'root', url: '/', views: {
    header: Header,
    navigation: Navigation,
    content: Content
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Header, Navigation, Content
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({states: [rootState], useHash: true}),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`Header`, `Navigation` and `Content` are three components which I want to display. They are very simple as for now and look similar to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class Header { }
```

and template is just a single word:

```
header
```

Here is `AppComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "LES.AdministrationDesk"
}
```

and its template:

```
<ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="navigation"></ui-view>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

I'm using `AngularJS@2.4.8` and `iu-router-ng2@1.0.0-beta4`

It would be much easier if the ui-router author would provide some working plunker example for multiple views, but I cannot find any.

Comment: Any particular reason for using ui-router with angular2+? Seems to me like Angular2's router does all the things ui-router could do.

Comment: we used ui-router with Angular 1 in production so we thought we can use it further

Comment: Angular 2 is a whole different beast... If I were you, I'd look into the core router's abilities and stick with it if it fits your requirements. I don't think ui-router is very popular with Angular2+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use angular 2 router. It`s not a good decision to use components from previous version of angular with current version.

```
<body>
<my-app>
    <main-header></main-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <main-footer></main-footer>
</my-app>
```

As for example. Main-header and main-footer will be present in this app all the time.
Inner components is easy to implement too.
Example of routes configuration:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: HomeView},
{path: 'contactUs', component: ContactUsView},
{path: 'ourService/:id', component: OurServiceView}
```

];

Comment: How did you solve the problem with loading your local css? I link them in the index.html but get 404

Comment: Some styles from cdn, some localy. Maybe you have wrong way of styles relatively to index.html? Right now I`m using webpack for bundling all styles in one.